# Rearrange pages in PDF

Tags: pdf

I want to print: 2 A5 pages on A4.

And my file need rearranged with No Rule.

But i don’t want to manual use drag/drop in Adobe pdf or software

Example:

Current file: 1,2,3...100

rearranged PDF: 1,2,7,9,3...100, 88, 99

Original file created by \documentclass{article} 
Note: No margin in newly pdf

Thank in advance

Comment: what does "no rule" mean? randomly?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: thanks. It is not random. Not rule, ex: 13,157, 28,1,2,99....and this reorder page number is manual input by me...

Comment: well use pdfpages and issue the correct page numbers ...

Answer (score 1):

On Unix/Linux (and perhaps others) you can use [pdfjam](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam) for most of your PDF mangling tasks.

That said, why do you need to rearrange pages? LaTeX is quite capable of handling back and forward references.